# Args and Tuples in Python

Tags: python

When you are trying to use *args, and I want to display a list of strings.

I attempted it via the code below but I end up receiving a TypeError stating `unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'`

```
def add(*args):
    sum = 0
    for i in args:
        sum += i
    return sum
print(add("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: 0 is an integer but "1", "2", ... are string. You have to cast them as integer first. (and don't use builtin function as variable name please -> `sum`): `sum += int(i)`

Comment: What output do you expect to get in your example? You are getting this error because `sum` is `int` and `i` is a string - python doesn't know how to add up those. So the solution depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: _I want to display a list of strings_ Even if the code worked, it would display an integer, not a list of strings.  Which do you actually want?

Comment: as an aside, you should probably use the built-in `sum`

Comment: Do you intend this to return 10 or "1234"?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing strings, so on your first loop iteration you're trying to add `"1"` to `0`. This will not work.

You convert the string to an `int`.

```
def add(*args):
    sum = 0
    for i in args:
        sum += int(i)
    return sum

print(add("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Of course, this raises the possibility of one of those strings not being something that can convert to an `int` in this case you will get a `ValueError` exception. If you wanted to just ignore those, you might do something like the following.

```
def add(*args):
    sum = 0
    for i in args:
        try:
            sum += int(i)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return sum

print(add("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use first arg as an initial value and add others to it. This way `add` can sum up all possible types of arguments:

```
def add(*args):
    it = iter(args)
    s = next(it)    # args first value
    for v in it:    # all others
        s += v
    return s


print(add(1, 2, 3, 4))
print(add('1', '2', '3', '4'))
print(add(['1', '2'], ['3', '4']))
```

> ```
> $ python add.py
> 10
> 1234
> ['1', '2', '3', '4']
> ```

Comment: This does not solve the specific problem of the OP.